# How to return individual dates from a date-time series in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a datetime column in a data frame. From that column i want to return every single day. In that df, I have 14 days and each day has so many values with even miliseconds.

So I want a output like
[2022-07-18, 2022-07-19,………………]

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['dates'],infer_datetime_format=True).dt.date`

Answer (score 2):

You can standardize the format with `.dt.date`. If it has not yet been converted into datetime, then use:

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'],infer_datetime_format=True).dt.date
```

Based on your comment, you can then filter the dates so:

```
filtered_dates = df[(df['Dates'] > start_date) & (df['Dates'] < end_date)]['Dates']
```

Comment: This gives me all d dates. I dont want that. I want just 14 days listed. this code gives me the whole series timestamp as date [y m d]. I need those 14 days just, not the whole series

Comment: Please see the edit.